# postgresql query to return the day of the week of the first day of the month two years from today

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, truncate

I used postgresql to solve the quesion, query to return the day of the week of the first day of the month two years from today. I was able to solve it with the query below, but I am not sure my query is correct, I just wanna make sure

select cast(date_trunc('month', current_date + interval '2 years') as date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly computing the first day of the month two years later with:

```
date_trunc('month', current_date + interval '2 years')
```

If you want the corresponding day of the week, you can use `extract()`;

```
extract(dow from date_trunc('month', current_date + interval '2 years'))
```

This gives you an integer value between 0 (Sunday) and 6 (Saturday)